# Align DIV contents not working

Tags: html, css

having trouble with DIV content alignment. I set the DIV to float right of the page, shouldn't the contents float right as well? The file-type input below the Unix Conversion textbox is not aligning to the right.

```
<div style="float: right; display: inline-block; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; zoom: 1;">
    <input style="width: 200; margin-right: -3px;" id="txtunix" type="text" value="Convert Unix Timestamp" onclick='cleartxtunix()'>
    <input class="button" style="margin-right: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 50em; border-bottom-right-radius: 50em;" type="button" value="Convert" onclick='displayunix()'>
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="file" id="fileinput" style="margin-right: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 50em; border-bottom-right-radius: 50em;">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the below element to be? Right of convert button?

Comment: please explain more your question

Comment: you must use float:right  or display: inline-block;

Comment: Yes I want it aligned to the right so both those round-edge ends of the top and bottom objects will be aligned (will meet) to the right.

Comment: @Dmitriy I already added that though. Do you mean use another float and inline-block for each of the elements?

Comment: @user3470997 Show a screenshot of what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the element is floated to the right, the content won't automatically be aligned to, but will inherit it's parents setting (default: left).

You'll need to add `text-align: right` to it, to make the text line up on the right side.

```
<div style="text-align: right; float: right; display: inline-block; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; zoom: 1;">
    <input style="width: 200; margin-right: -3px;" id="txtunix" type="text" value="Convert Unix Timestamp" onclick='cleartxtunix()'>
    <input class="button" style="margin-right: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 50em; border-bottom-right-radius: 50em;" type="button" value="Convert" onclick='displayunix()'>
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="file" id="fileinput" style="margin-right: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 50em; border-bottom-right-radius: 50em;">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but would like an explanation why, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: Wasn't me :/ It's the ghost of SO :s

Comment: Where do I add text-align? To the div's style? Is text-align still compatible to major and new version browsers?

Comment: @user3470997, I added the code to the answer, including the text-alignment. And for your info, anyone can up/downvote a question or answer.

Comment: Indeed, your answer is correct, setting text-align to `right` will solve the problem.  Not sure why the down vote...

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, just wasn't sure if it's compatible to all browsers but most of us use Chrome so we're good :)

Comment: @user3470997, to check the compatibility of styles, check http://caniuse.com/. But text-align is a most common style and supported by all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `text-align: right` on the floated parent block, `.panel` in the example shown below.

Note that the `#fileinput` styling needs some attention, but the snippet shows the alignment that you need.

Minor bug fix: Remember to add units to `width: 200px`.

Finally, the child elements can be either inline or inline-block (`display` property values).  The choice depends on your design and styling.

```css
.panel {
  float: right;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: right;
}
#txtunix {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: -3px;
}
.button {
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50em;
}
#fileinput {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <input id="txtunix" type="text" value="Convert Unix Timestamp">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Convert">
  <br>
  <input class="button" id="fileinput" type="file" value="">
</div>
```